# Why is the identity function from $\Bbb R$ with the Euclidean metric to $\Bbb R$ with the discrete metric not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

> Using only the definition of sequential continuity, show an example that $f(x) = x: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R'$ is not continuous, where $\Bbb R'$ has the discrete topology.

So the definition of sequential continuity is where if $x_n \to x$, then $f(x_n) \to f(x)$. The given example was $x_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ which converges to $1$ as $n \to \infty$ in $\Bbb R$, but it does not converge to $1$ in $\Bbb R'$. Why does $x_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n} \not\to 1$?

Comment: In topological terms: The open set $\{f(x)\}$ does not contain any element in the sequence, so there will be no positive integer $k$ such that $n>k$ implies that $f(x_n)$ reside in all  open sets containing the point $f(x)$.

Comment: Metric spaces :Using the discrete metric $d$, $d(f(x),f(x_n))=1$ for all $n$ so given $0<\epsilon <1$ there will be no  positive integer $k$ such that $n>k$ implies that $d(f(x),f(x_n))<\epsilon$. unless of course the sequence is constant, then d(f(x),f(x_n))=0 for all $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric all sets are open, including singletons, but singletons are not open in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean metric. This definition ($f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous iff the preimage of every open set is open) is one way of showing this.

Using the sequential definition of continuity, if you prefer, consider $\{1/n\}$ which converges to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean metric, but doesn't converge at all in  $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete metric. In fact, only constant sequences converge in this space.

Comment: (eventually constant sequences)